# Move image around (css3 transform) with touchmove on iPad

Tags: javascript, performance, ipad, css, transform

I have an image which I would like to move around on my iPad3

The problem is that it isn't going as good as I hoped for, the image doesn't move smooth and is moving behind the gesture.

What I have is as follows (3MB base64 image)

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ....">
```

css:

```
img {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

And the javascript is

```
img.on('touchstart', function (e) {
     var diffX = e.pageX;
     var diffY = e.pageY;
     img.on('touchmove', function (e) {
         translateX  += e.pageX - diffX;   
         translateY += e.pageY - diffY; 

         img.css({'-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px)'});

         diffX = e.pageX;
         diffY = e.pageY;

     });             
     return false;
})
...
```

It works great on my laptop, but not my iPad3.
I also tried requestAnimationFrame, but then nothing happens until I stop moving. Any suggestion how to improve the performance on my iPad ?

Comment: don't use jquery if you want performance.

Answer (score 1):

This does most of the math outside of the touchmove function
and sets the webkittransform directly without passing by a very long jquery css function.
it also uses the 3d transition witch isn't properly set with just adding translate3d in css file with the ios7

```
var sx,sy,cx=0,cy=0,img=document.images[0];
img.addEventListener('touchstart',ts,false);
img.addEventListener('touchmove',tm,false);
img.addEventListener('touchend',te,false);
function ts(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 sx=e.pageX-cx;
 sy=e.pageY-cy;
}
function tm(e){
 this.style.webkitTransform='translate3d('+
 (e.pageX-sx)+'px,'+(e.pageY-sy)+'px,0)';
}
function te(e){
 cx=e.pageX-sx;
 cy=e.pageY-sy;
}
```

another point is ... even if you have the ipad 3 it can't handle a big image like that so consider putting all inside a `div` with `overflow:hidden` this will increase the performance too.

```
div{
 width:400px;/*try 100%*/
 height:400px;/*try 100%*/
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Mouse move  example (not touch but its the same except you don't need the isup check)

http://jsfiddle.net/AtBUh/

Comment: const pageY = (event as TouchEvent).touches[0].pageY;